# How to inform cmake to prioritize a certain file

Tags: build, cmake

Is there a way to inform CMake to produce build graph such that the build process prioritizes specific file/files?

Basically, I hope to get compile build time errors/warnings from a file as soon as possible in the build and especially when a lot of files are changed, for example after a `git checkout`.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a file named `path/to/file/name.cpp` manually by running

```
make -C <build_dir>/path/to/file name.o
```

Comment: While this is a good suggestion, this is one side of the story. It compiles a file and its dependencies but not its dependents. If there's some trickery to do the other side of the graph, it'll be a great solution